# Cycling windows - ugly apps icons

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

How to change these icons? There aren't the same as those of the installed package (Numix)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlUqY.png]

If you can't change them how to hide them?
Thanks.

Comment: Sick desktop **:)**

Comment: Possible solution, https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=10938.0

Comment: Did you try updating the icon cache? gtk-update-icon-cache -f -t /usr/share/icons/<theme_name>

Answer (score 1):

How to install and use new icon sets in *ubuntu:

**First Method**

Download some icon packs from [deviantart](http://malysss.deviantart.com/art/) and extract them to ~/.icons. If this directory doesn’t exist, create one using the following command:

```
mkdir ~/.icons
```

The following command will download and unzip an icon pack (that I think is very cool) called Uniform by 0rax0:

(For the current user only)

```
wget -O ~/.icons/uniform-icons http://www.deviantart.com/download/453054609/uniform_icon_theme_by_0rax0-d7hqj69.zip?token=a235ea7bccd82b62276464a126eb9d665c511c45&ts=1444170923
```

(or for all users on the system)

```
wget -O /usr/share/icons/uniform-icons http://www.deviantart.com/download/453054609/uniform_icon_theme_by_0rax0-d7hqj69.zip?token=a235ea7bccd82b62276464a126eb9d665c511c45&ts=1444170923
```

Now, once you've installed the icon set, you can use Unity Tweak Tool to change the icon theme.

Use the following command to install Unity Tweak Tool:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Once installed, run `unity-tweak-tool` from a terminal, or run the app from the menu, and click on Appearance then click on Icons.

You can select your preferred icon set from what is available here. And just keep adding more icons you find on the net.

**Second Method**

Lets see some beautiful icon sets available for Ubuntu Unity (probably Gnome and others as well, but I haven't tested):

To install Moka icons pack in Ubuntu and other Linux distributions, use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:moka/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install moka-icon-theme
```

Numix Circle icon theme. There are more themes, along with some wallpapers available in the Numix PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install numix-icon-theme numix-icon-theme-circle
```

Also check out Plateau icon themes Ubuntu 14.04
You can download the flat icon themes Plateau from Deviantart.
And another one is  called Simple but that is Gnome only.

Comment: I have icons installed from the repository Numix.